# How to fix Django error: " 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo' " on database read

Tags: django, admin, azure-sql-database, django-timezone

I am deploying my Django project on Windows Azure. I was using SQLite as a database server and everything was ok. When I have deployed My project, I decided to connect it with an SQL Azure Database but it seems that this solution created some errors. I am no longer able to edit users profiles. I get always this error :

> ```
> AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/1/
> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
> ```

Comment: Stacktrace would probably help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 4):

This error happens when your database contains date-time stamps like this:

`0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`

*(this can happen in MySQL if you delete or overwrite a previous date with MySQLWorkbench)*

When you try to retrieve these records in a Django model object, you will get an exception from the [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) timezone library:

```
AttributeError 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

You should edit these dates in your database first, and set them to more recent dates, like `2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000` or set to `NULL` (but not blank).

See:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Jg_9fQ3jMcU

See also:

- [#1292 - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292628/1292-incorrect-date-value-0000-00-00)
- [Error in mysql when setting default value for DATE or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime)
- [How to store NULL values in datetime fields in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691117/how-to-store-null-values-in-datetime-fields-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue trying to use `django-pyodbc-azure` database backend with Django (1.5.1): by default it stores `DateTimeField` fields in your DB as `datetime2(7)`, which looks to be still unsupported in Django.
In my case I added the option `'use_legacy_datetime' : True` in `settings.py`, like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME' : '<MYDBNAME>',
        'USER': '<MYDBUSER>',
        'PASSWORD': '<MYDBPWD>',
        'HOST': '<MYHOST>',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_mars': True,
            'use_legacy_datetime' : True, # I added this line
        },
    },
}
```

I found my solution [here](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/blob/azure/README.rst#options).
I don't know Azure platform well, so I don't know if this is exactly your case, if not you can still modify your database replacing `datetime2(N)` fields with good old `datetime` ones.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is `use_mars` and how did you find it?