# Django: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'. Production server only

Tags: django, wsgi, pytz, datetime2, django-pyodbc-azure

I'm stumped. With my local set up (python manage.py runserver) everything runs fine. With my production set up (wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer), I get `'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'` when my program tries to convert datetime2(7) from the database to local time in the pytz module. Using Django 1.9.

- Both set ups use django-pyodbc-azure to connect to the same mssql database. In fact to troubleshoot this, both use the same settings files.

  ```
  # settings.py
  ...

  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
          'NAME': 'dbname',
          'OPTIONS': {
              'use_mars': True,
              'use_legacy_datetime': True,
              'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
          }
      }
  }

  ...

  # Relevant to runserver command:
  WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'
  ```
- Production is run by running this file:

  ```
  # deploy_server.py

  from . import wsgi
  sn = socket.gethostname()

  server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
      ('0.0.0.0', 8009), wsgi.application, server_name=sn,
  )
  server.start()
  ```
- Local is run with Djangos runserver command
- wsgi.py:

  ```
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  application = get_wsgi_application()
  ```

I initially had the same problem locally, but configuring the database with the options shown fixed that.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Did you try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492031/how-to-fix-this-error-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-tzinfo?rq=1 ?

Comment: @karthikr - Yes, that is how I fixed the problem when it occurred with my local settings. For some reason that solution doesn't work with my production set up.