# Cannot alter default value of a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a table in mysql with 3 columns. added_date(datetime), completion_date(date) and expired(date). completion_date and expired columns have their default value set to 0000-00-00. Now I'm trying to create an index for the table by the added_date column for which I'm using this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE listings ADD INDEX added_date (added_date)
```

This gives me an error saying `Invalid default value for 'completion_date'` So now to change the default value to null in my table I'm using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `listings` CHANGE `completion_date` `completion_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Which gives an error saying `Invalid default value for 'expired'` and the same vice versa. Now I've also tried creating 2 alter table statements like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `listings` CHANGE `completion_date` `completion_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `listings` CHANGE `expired` `expired` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

But this again gave me the same error saying `Invalid default value for 'expired'`

Comment: Addeddate is not a good value for the date  column, try current_date( ) function at the place.

Comment: Do you mean `ALTER TABLE listings ADD INDEX current_date()`?

Comment: @H2O could you provide full table description, if you execute `ALTER TABLE listings ADD INDEX added_date (added_date)` it has nothing to do with `completion_date`

Comment: have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691117/how-to-store-null-values-in-datetime-fields-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to modify the column type:

```
create table t1 (c1 datetime not null );

alter table t1 
    modify c1 datetime null default null;
```

For more information, visit the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html